# ruby on rails: how to include a local variable in a select statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I'm trying to iterate over recipes extracted from my DB, parse the ingredients out of each recipe and insert the ingredients into their own table.
The problem is that I don't know how to include the current ingredient variable in my inner select:
currently I'm getting the following error:

*ExtractIngredients.rb:21:in `query': Unknown column 'ing' in 'field list' (Mysql::Error)*

Could you please tell me how to include "ing" in my select statement?

Thanks,
Li

```
begin

db = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'recs'
results = db.query "SELECT id, freeText FROM recipes"

nRows = results.num_rows

for i in 0..nRows-1
    curRow = results.fetch_row
recipeInd = curRow[0]
    recipeFreeText = curRow[1]

    ingredients = getIngredients(recipeFreeText).to_s.scan(/\'(\w+)\'/).flatten

    ingredients.each do |ing|
            db = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'recs'

            # In the next awful select statement I'm trying to insert the current ingredient to the ingredient table if it isn't already there
         db.query "INSERT INTO ingredient(name, created_at, updated_at) SELECT ing, created_at, updated_at FROM dummytable WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM ingredient WHERE Name = ing)=0"

        ingInd = db.query "SELECT id FROM ingredient WHERE name=ing"
            db.query "INSERT INTO ingredients_recipes(ingredient_id, recipe_id) ingInd, recipeInd"
    end     
end

end
```

Comment: You almost never want to be directly querying the database from Rails. Why do you need to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string interpolation like any other Ruby string: `#{ing}`

That said, if this is Rails, why are you doing anything like this? And creating a new MySQL per ingredient? Most of this is baked in to the framework.

Comment: thx :) I am new in rails, could you pls give me a simple example / reference to the right way to do this ? (I only need to run it once so I don't want to put too much effort in it)

Comment: @user429400 If only running it once then it probably doesn't matter, but any if the Rails DB tutorials cover model relationships etc.

Answer (score 0):

By using interpolation

```
"..... WHERE Name = '#{ing}' ...."
```

---

If you are using Rails, why don't you use the Models for that task, instead of raw sql?